# Magento 2.3.X - Required PHP extension 'Imagick' was not loaded

Tags: magento2.3

Magento 2.3.2 when I set image adapter for ImageMagick images on front-end not load `Shows placeholder`.

When I run

```
bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

it says Required PHP extension `Imagick` was not loaded.

[image: imagemagick extension is loaded]

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992604/5577053

Answer (score 2):

To fix it, set the `PHP GD2` value for the

> ADVANCED → Developer → Image Processing Settings → Image Adapter configuration option

Also, if `imagick` is not installed on your server then install it with the below command

```
sudo yum install php7-imagick
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: imagick is installed, you have screenshot above. i set imagemagick on magento settings

Comment: Have you tried ADVANCED → Developer → Image Processing Settings → Image Adapter configuration option (PHP GD2) this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to install the package for the right PHP version. For PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-imagick
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the PHP imagick module on your server, for CentOS you should be able to use:

```
sudo yum install php7-imagick
```

To install the module.

If that doesn't work, you can follow: https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/install-imagemagick-php-imagick-centos/

Installing on CentOS 6: https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-imagemagick-on-centos-6

for ubantu

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

Comment: imagick is installed, you have screenshot above. i set imagemagick on magento settings

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the other solution did not work but this one. So you could try ones if it works for you.
My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

To install Imagick run bellow command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

For specific PHP version (in my case 7.1):

```
sudo apt-get install php8.2-imagick
```

Then restart apache:

```
sudo sudo systemctl restart nginx php8.2-fpm
```

To check if the extension has been installed:

```
php -m | grep imagick
```

[image: Screenshort of the command]